# Visually structure PHP programs

Tags: php, class-design

I use mysql workbench, to visually structure my relational database tables.

Does a similar program exist to visually structure PHP programs?  i.e. visually structure and connect classes, functions, pages etc etc?

I use Linux, so no Windows only programs please.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320024/are-there-any-php-code-visualization-tools

Comment: @Martijn Dijksterhuis, that link is to a question asking for a tool to convert existing php to visual form, I am asking for a tool to design classes from scratch, with a possible option to convert the classes to code, so I don't see how this question is a dupe of the link you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans has a plugin for doing UML. Using this you can create analysis diagrams that include your classes (therefore their methods and attributes). If your pages are also classes, then you don't need more.

But basically you won't find something that allows you to also structure both your codes and pages all together, it doesn't make sense to me, you have to create your own diagrams in these cases (see Dia: http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)

**Edit**

Gotta check if the Netbeans UML plugin does convert to PHP output. It sure does for Java, but haven't tried for PHP.

I've just come across http://argouml.tigris.org/

It has PHP support and seems really nice. I also found: http://www.gentleware.com/

Comment: UML is exactly what you need.